# Как заставить программу вернуть в начало метода main после выполнения очередного условия if? JAVA

Tags: java

Вот для примера листинг

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System. in );
    int n = 0;
    System.out.print("Введите число ");
    n = scn.nextInt();
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print("Ваше число = 0, введите другое число\n ");
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("Ваше число чётное ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Ваше число нечётное ");
    }
}
```

Допустим мы ввели 0. Выводит сообщение мол введите другое число и на этом работа программы заканчивается, а как сделать чтобы начало отрабатывать с начала ?

Comment: Кстати, 0 чётный :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно чаще всего для этого используются управляющие конструкции такие, как `while` и  `do-while` Реже используется `for`, когда нет конечного перечисления .

Нвпример

```
int n = 0;
do
{
    System.out.print("Введите число ( 0 - exit ): ");
    n = scn.nextInt();

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        if( n%2 == 0) {  System.out.print("Ваше число чётное "); }
        else { System.out.print("Ваше число нечётное ");}
    }
} while ( n != 0 );
```

Или, например,

```
while ( true )
{
    int n = 0;

    System.out.print("Введите число ( 0 - exit ): ");
    n = scn.nextInt();

    if ( n == 0 ) break;

    if( n%2 == 0) {  System.out.print("Ваше число чётное "); }
    else { System.out.print("Ваше число нечётное ");}
}
```

Я сделал n равным 0 условием выхода из цикла (когда-то же пользователь должен покинуть программу, не так ли?:) ).
Вы можете выбрать любое условие выхода из цикла на ваше усмотрение.

Кстати сказать, на мой взгляд использование `break`  с меткой - это плохой стиль программирования. Я не советую его использовать там, где легко можно обойтись без этого предложения.

Comment: При n = 0 ваш код скажет, что число чётное.

Comment: @LEQADA  Спасибо, это легко исправить. В принципе не в этом суть дело, так как вопрос не о том, что там распечатать, а как  сделать неоднократное выполнение кода.:)

Comment: Закройте скобку вложенного `if`

Comment: @LEQADA  Еще раз вам спасибо.:)

Comment: А что означает !n в строке  if ( !n ) break; ?

Comment: @Ustin Я надеюсь, что это эквивалентно if ( n == 0 )

Comment: а понятно, просто сокращённая форма, спасибо

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не надейтесь. Такого в Java нет. Есть `n==0` и `n!=0`.

Comment: @LEQADA Я думал, что только в C# такого нет. В Java тоже такого нет?

Comment: Исправьте на `if ( n==0 ) break;`

Comment: @Ustin  Говорят, что в Java так нельзя писать. Я написал по привычке, так как обычно здесь в ответах имею дело с C++. Поэтому я исправлю на if ( n == 0 ) Но вы можете сами проверить, работает ли это условие в Java  или нет.:)

Comment: Да дело в том, что в Java `if` принимает только boolean. А в C++ альтернатива `true` - 1, а `false` - 0. Поэтому их можно использовать в условиях.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n;

  LOOP: while (true) {
    System.out.print("Введите число ");
    n = scn.nextInt();

    if (n == 0){
      System.out.println("Ваше число = 0, выход из программы");
      break LOOP;
    } else if (n%2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("Ваше число чётное");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Ваше число нечётное");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Scanner RepetitionMethod = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {

    System.out.print("Would you like to explore the garage? (yes or no):");
    String quest = RepetitionMethod.nextLine();

    if (quest.equals("yes")||quest.equals("y")||quest.equals("1")) {
        System.out.println("You see: Tv, Books, Car ");
        break;
    } else if (quest.equals("no")||quest.equals("n")||quest.equals("0")) {
        System.out.println("You not see ");
        break;

    }else{
        System.out.println("Error you need write (yes or no)");
        System.out.println("Try again!");

    }

    }
    RepetitionMethod.close();
}
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]